# how to get setup using XCode/Appium using Appium.app

Tags: appium

I am trying to automate the test cases in real apple device using appium but not able to do so.
Need help to setup the appium from appium.app not from terminal to test real apple devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are currently issues with the current release of Appium.app (1.2.0). You cannot use Appium.app alone to run Appium.

- You need to install Appium via [Source](http://appium.io/slate/en/v1.2.0/?ruby#toc_9) or [Appium-version-manager](https://www.npmjs.org/package/appium-version-manager)
- You need to install XCode
- You need to install XCode's command line tools

Follow [these setup instructions](http://appium.io/slate/en/v1.2.0/?ruby#toc_9).

Then follow [these instructions](http://appium.io/slate/en/v1.2.0/?ruby#toc_48) to get the application ready for testing.

After that, run a simple test in your language of choice. Examples [here](https://github.com/appium/appium/tree/master/sample-code/examples/)

Once you get that working on the simulator, you need to prepare your application for testing on a real device by archiving the Application into an `.ipa` file signed with a **Development** certificate that contains your target device's UDID.

THEN, you can supply the `udid` and `deviceName` arguments to Appium server/desired_capabilities as defined in the [desired_caps document](http://appium.io/slate/en/v1.2.0/?ruby#toc_56).